# Не запускается связка ruby/unicorn/nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, redmine

Добрый день, коллеги!

Дано:
Сервер с несколькими веб-ресурсами, которые отдает nginx + php-fpm. Здесь проблем нет.
Развёрнут redmine, опубликован через связку unicorn + nginx. До вчерашнего дня всё работало, потом стало выпадать в bad gateway.

Когда сломалось, в логах было так:

**tail /var/log/nginx/error.log**:

```
[error] 2904#0: *50 connect() to unix:/home/redmine/redmine/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: some.ip.addr.ess, server: red.domainname.zone, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/redmine/redmine/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock:/", host: "red.domainname.zone"
```

Изменил адрес сокета в nginx и unicorn, перезапустил.

**unicorn.rb:**

```
worker_processes 1 
working_directory "/home/redmine/redmine/"

preload_app true

timeout 30

listen "/tmp/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

pid "/home/redmine/redmine/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid" 
stderr_path "/home/redmine/redmine/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "/home/redmine/redmine/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/redmine.conf**:

```
upstream redmine {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name red.somedomain.zone;
        client_max_body_size 200m;
        root /srv/redmine/;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @ruby;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|gif|png|js|css|ico)$ {
                root /home/redmine/redmine/public;
                expires 7d;
                error_page 404 502 504 = @ruby;
        }

        location @ruby {
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_pass http://redmine; #upstream redmine
        }
}
```

Сокет создается, попробовал поменять владельца на nginx и права на 777:

srwxrwxrwx.  1 nginx nginx    0 сен  6 11:20 unicorn.sock

Но в логах теперь другая ошибка, которая никак не уходит:

```
[crit] 15180#0: *4 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: some.ip.addr.ess, server: red.somedomain.zone, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock:/", host: "red.somedomain.zone"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Unicorn stderr.log циклические записи:

```
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913416 #16165] ERROR -- : listen loop error: Socket operation on non-socket - accept (Errno::ENOTSOCK)
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913656 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:657:in `kgio_tryaccept'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913720 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:657:in `worker_loop'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913757 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:508:in `spawn_missing_workers'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913787 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:132:in `start'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913833 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913864 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913891 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913919 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913955 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.913986 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
E, [2016-09-06T12:57:09.914015 #16165] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails3/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
```

Comment: Совершенно напрасно перемещаете сокет из unix:/home/redmine/redmine/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock в unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock - там его какие-ниудь cron-задания по очистке снесут еще быстрее. Посмотрите логи /home/redmine/redmine/log/unicorn.stdout.log и /home/redmine/redmine/log/unicorn.stderr.log - в них ничего интересного нет? А также log/production.log - в них никаких зацепок нет? Сам unicorn работает ps aux | grep unicorn?

Comment: Unicorn работает в ps aux вижу его, файл сокета создается. Перенёс сейчас в /var/run/unicorn.sock (Тоже решил не рисковать с кроном).  В production.log нет ничего нитересного, последняя запись  от времени "Когда работало". Вывод stderr.log сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: `unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock` <- а разве не два слэша надо в unix-URL для указания абсолютного пути?

Comment: `Socket operation on non-socket` <- там что, файл лежит вместо сокета?

Comment: @D-side Там - это где? Unicorn сам при запуске создаёт файл сокета. А на счёт 2х слешей - вроде нет. На всякий случай попробовал поменять - ноль реакции.

Comment: какой руби в системе дефолтный? после чего появилась проблема? сдается мне в хосте нжинкса не верно root /srv/redmine/;

Comment: @JamesMaynard Дефолтный руби 2.2.2 на 3 рельсах, Рут не при чём, не запускается именно юникорн (Что видно из лога stderr)